# Pivot Tables without SUM/Count or a better method

Tags: sql, sql-server, pivot-table

I have the following two tables:

Employee Table

```
id name
1  John Doe
```

Products Table

```
id category  units
1  Chairs    5
1  Computers 2
1  Pens      40
```

When I run the following

```
Select name, category, units FROM employee 
JOIN Products 
ON products.id = employee.id
```

I get three rows of data:

```
name        category    units
john doe    chairs      5
john doe    computers   2
john doe    pens        40
```

I want my output to look like:

```
name        chairs  computers   pens
john doe    5       2           40
```

I tried pivot table but it requires me to have a sum/count field but I do not want a to sum any data. Is there a trick or a better way than Pivot to get the output above?

Comment: You should be able to just use the max() function where you think you need a sum or count.

Comment: What result would you expect if there were two rows for john doe\chairs with different units?

Answer (score 0):

This one can be achievable using dynamic queries.

> 1. Get your distinct categories to generate columns
> 2. Build your sql string with dynamic columns
> 3. Pivot your columns.

```
declare  @cols nvarchar(max);
declare  @sql nvarchar(1000);
//generate category columns
select @cols =
    STUFF((select N'],[' + category
       from (select distinct category
          from Products) AS t1   
       FOR XML PATH('')
    ), 1, 2, '') + N']';

set @sql = N'Select name, units, ' + @cols + N'  FROM employee 
                JOIN Products 
                ON products.id = employee.id  ) t1
            pivot 
            (
                max(t1.category)
                for t1.category in (' + @cols + N')
            ) p '

exec sp_executesql @sql;
```